# Corner radius is not working in Jetpack Glance Widget

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget, glance

My Glance image is set like this:

```
Image(
    provider = ImageProvider(
        bitmap
    ),
    contentDescription = "Image",
    modifier = GlanceModifier
        .size(70.dp)
        .imageCornerRadius()
        .clickable(
             actionRunCallback<StartAppCallback>(
                 parameters = actionParametersOf(
                     StartAppCallback.WIDGET_TYPE to type.value,
                     StartAppCallback.ID to model.id
                 )
             )
       ),
)
```

and image corner radius is set like:

```
fun GlanceModifier.imageCornerRadius(): GlanceModifier {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        this.cornerRadius(android.R.dimen.system_app_widget_inner_radius)
    } else {
        this.cornerRadius(8.dp)
    }
}
```

If it is a bug, and there are no workarounds, I will edit my question with the issue tracker link. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: As described in the doc. `cornerRadius` adds rounded corners for the current view.
**Note: Only works on Android S+.**

Comment: IOW, your `if`/`else` in your `imageCornerRadius()` is pointless, as the `cornerRadius()` call will be ignored on older devices. If you want rounded corners on older devices, you will need to modify the bitmap itself.

Comment: Please close this question since it has been answered